# Getting base64 string on scraping image src

Tags: javascript, base64, screen-scraping

I am scraping image src, title, price etc from website but it gives base64 string in place of image src. When i'm appending all these scraped data to uri, it shows error long uri. How to slow this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're getting a base64 string as the img src, it sounds as though the image is encoded inline.

> data: URIs are a very useful way to embed small items of data into a
>   URL—rather than link to an external resource, the URL contains the
>   actual encoded data.

> An HTML fragment embedding a picture of small red dot:
>
> ```
> <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
> AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
> 9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
> ```

In the example above, if you were to base64 decode the string (minus the `data:image/png,base64,` part), you would get the data of a PNG image which you could write to disk as a file.

- http://dopiaza.org/tools/datauri/examples/index.php
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

Comment: is there any way to get actual link rather than this base64 string

Comment: There *is* no link, that's the point. There is no file on the server that you can access with a URL, instead the data of the image *is* the base64 encoded string.

Comment: remove the bit that looks like `data:image/png,base64,` then with the remainder, you can use a base64 decode function. In PHP, it's `base64_decode`, in Javascript it's `atob`

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful

Comment: @DalHundal in my case THERE IS a URL and I've copy-pasted-go into browser and there is the image in full size. Yet BS4 and Python3 scrape the <img src..> and converts it to Base64, so no this is not the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Same comment as above. I definitely see a url when I inspect the element in a browser but when I use Scrapy it turns it into a base64 encoded string. Argh.